# error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `try_successful_origin`

Tags: polkadot, xcm, cargo, features

I am seeing this compile error with the `xcm-builder` when building our chain `w/Polkadot 0.9.38`. What should I change to fix it?  This issue is also discussed here https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/149 but I wasn't able to get it to work.

```rs
      error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `try_successful_origin`
         --> /home/test/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-4038f27d5e4ea2e8/097ffd2/xcm/xcm-builder/src/origin_conversion.rs:247:1
          |
      247 | / impl<RuntimeOrigin: OriginTrait + Clone, Conversion: Convert<RuntimeOrigin, MultiLocation>>
      248 | |     EnsureOrigin<RuntimeOrigin> for EnsureXcmOrigin<RuntimeOrigin, Conversion>
          | |______________________________________________________________________________^ missing `try_successful_origin` in implementation
          |
          = help: implement the missing item: `fn try_successful_origin() -> Result<OuterOrigin, ()> { todo!() }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enabled the `runtime-benchmarks` feature of the `xcm-builder` in the `Cargo.toml` of your crate.

Here the example - https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/fa1d47f3686bfd78d8bee320d84b3c67d1fdf003/parachains/runtimes/collectives/collectives-polkadot/Cargo.toml#L100